# Custom widgets as elements in ListView

Tags: python, kivy

I just want to write a chat-room application and want to realise a messages list in ListView so - message concept

[image]

But I have no idea how to do this becouse list adapter on kivy can only accept a ListItemButton or ListItemLabel elements of the list. He doesn't accept the type of my custom classes and even the simple BoxLayout.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you no longer use ListView since it is deprecated, kivy recommends using RecycleView, the concept is similar to ListView, there is a data field that is a list of dictionaries, where the dictionary is the properties that the widget that uses the view receives for create each item.

Assuming that the custom widget already has it, then you must expose all the properties that can be modified by the list, in the example there are 3 properties: source_image, title and message.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Builder.load_string('''

<CustomWidget@BoxLayout>:

    source_image: ""
    title: ""
    message: ""

    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Image:
        source: root.source_image
        size_hint_x: 1
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: 2
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: root.title
            size: self.texture_size
            size_hint_y: None
        Label:
            text: root.message

<View>:
    viewclass: 'CustomWidget'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class View(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'source_image': "heart.png", 'title': "title{}".format(i), 'message': "message"} for i in range(100)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runTouchApp(View())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use QtWebKit for you chat program, because it's ideal to use HTML markup in chats - it give you **infinite** posibilites of decoration your chat massages.

You can embed images with <img> tag, make text <strong>bold</strong> or <i>italic<i>

You can embed youtube (and other) videos with <video> tag

And all you need is:

1. Create instance of QtWebKit
2. Inside of it, put simple html-file with JavaScript function, that would handle some outer Signal, take inbound data and put it to the html
3. Outside, after message arrive, wrap it into HTML, and pass to QtWebKit.

Comment: Thank u for your answer, but i need a realisation on Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) for that.

> The RecycleView provides a flexible model for viewing selected sections of large data sets. It aims to prevent the performance degradation that can occur when generating large numbers of widgets in order to display many data items.

It uses...

> ...dicts to generate instances of the viewclass as required

and by `viewclass` it means your custom-made list-item widget.